# Adding a comma at every third number character

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I have a variable `myCash`, which is printed into an `h1` element using javaScript's `innerHTML`. I found a function online that puts a comma after every third character from the end of the number so that the number is easier to read. I've tried for a couple of hours now sending my variable `myCash` into the function and then print it on the screen. I CANNOT get it to work.

I've tried just alerting the new variable to the screen after page load or by pressing a button, but I get nothing and the alert doesn't even work. Here's the comma insert function:

```
function commaFormatted(amount) {
    var delimiter = ","; // replace comma if desired
    amount = new String(amount);
    var a = amount.split('.',2)
    var d = a[1];
    var i = parseInt(a[0]);
    if(isNaN(i)) { return ''; }
    var minus = '';
    if(i < 0) { minus = '-'; }
    i = Math.abs(i);
    var n = new String(i);
    var a = [];
    while(n.length > 3)
    {
        var nn = n.substr(n.length-3);
        a.unshift(nn);
        n = n.substr(0,n.length-3);
    }
    if(n.length > 0) { a.unshift(n); }
    n = a.join(delimiter);
    if(d.length < 1) { amount = n; }
    else { amount = n + '.' + d; }
    amount = minus + amount;
    return amount;
}
```

now when I want my variable to change I've tried it a few different ways including this:

`var newMyCash = commaFormatted(myCash);
 alert(newMyCash);`

and this:

`alert(commaFormatted(myCash);`

Where of course `myCash` equal some large number;

This does absolutely nothing! What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: Can you post it on jsFiddle ?

Comment: What is the 'myCash' variable? e.g. 4800.00 or "480000" etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not my function, but I hope it helps you.

```
function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Usage:

```
var newMyCash = addCommas( myCash ); alert( newMyCash );
```

Source: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html

Answer (score 1):

Also,

Try this as a drop in replacement and try alerting the response:

http://phpjs.org/functions/number_format:481

Do you see any errors in the console of your browser (usually f12)?

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely not passing in a number that contains a decimal, which the function expects.

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/jR8W8/1/)